# Nested fragments with viewpager and bottom navigation

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i am stuck at nested fragments , some one please guide me a little bit. i am in learning phase...

actually i am using a bottomNavigationView and popluate fragments and when selecting an item, one fragment has a view pager and tab layout in it, and loading list data from fire base. the problem is that when a fragment with viewpager in it selected, data fetched successfuly but not populated in list view, but when i swite view pages the listview is populated . any one please help me for this problem or guide me where to put network calls in fragment or something else solution of it.

First Fragment which have Viewpager in .

```
public class explore extends Fragment {

public static explore Instance = null;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private Activity activity;
private Context context;
private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

public static explore getInstance() {
    if (Instance == null) {
        Instance = new explore();
    }
    return Instance;
}

public explore() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    activity = (Activity) getActivity();
    context = getActivity();
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_explore, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View v, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.tabs_Explore);
    viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_Explore);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    List<Category> categories = new FirebaseHelper(getActivity()).getCategoriesList();
    pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), categories);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

pager's first fragment means(ChildFragment)

```
public class categories extends Fragment {

private static categories Obj = null;


private RecyclerView listView;

private List<Category> categoryList;

private CategoryAdapter categoryAdapter;


public categories() {
    categoryList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public static categories getInstance() {
    if (Obj == null) {
        Obj = new categories();
    }
    return Obj;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    listView = v.findViewById(R.id.mRecycler);
    listView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
    helper.attachToRecyclerView(listView);
    categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), categoryList);
    listView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);


    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        categoryList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("data");
        categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Comment: add code for fragment containing viewpager and fragments inside viewpager

Comment: i edited check please

Comment: umm i dont think so , because when swipe views and again come back to that fragment it populate list data..

Comment: move `categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), categoryList);
    listView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);` inside `onActivityCreated` after you get `categoryList` and remove `categoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: ok i m trying...

Comment: didn't works :/